# Rename/alias method name of instance (in Python)

Tags: python

I have some graph processing functionality. It defines a class Edge and my_graph_algo:

```
class Edge:
    def connectsNodes(self, n1, n2):
        ....

def my_graph_algo(edge, more args):
    ...
    x = edge.connectsNodes(...)
    ...

e = Edge()
my_graph_algo(e)
```

So far, nothing special.

Now let's think of a `Friendship` and of a `Road`:

```
class Friendship:
    def areFriends(self, f1, f2):
        ...

class Road:
    def connectsTowns(self, t1, t2):
        ...
```

These exhibit the same behavior as a graph edge: They connect two things. So we could want to use `my_graph_algo(...)` with a `Friendship` or a `Road` as argument. Unfortunately, they ar not compatible with `my_graph_algo(...)` as they do not provide `connectsNodes` but they provide semantically identical `areFriends` and `connectsTowns`.

So I'd like to somehow dynamically rename/alias those function upon function call, something like:

```
f = Friendship()
my_graph_algo(f see areFriends as connectsNodes) # here

r = Road()
my_graph_algo(r see connectsTowns as connectsNodes) # and here
```

I know some techniques that can be used in that case, but which are not exactly what I'm asking for:

1. Define `Friendship` and `Road` as subtype of `Edge`, providing a function `connectsNodes`. Bad if you can not or do not want to change those classes.
2. Create adapter classes which adapt `Friendship` and `Road` to `Edge`. Tedious if you want to use such an "aliasing" technique in various cases.
3. Define a lambda function upon function call that "redirects" to the respective method. Would require to change `my_graph_algo(...)`.

**Is there a solution that would not require the modification of the existing classes/functions and would not require introduction of additional classes? Something that would provide a rename/alias right in place.**

Furthermore: How would it look if argument `edge` would actually be a list of objects representing an edge.

The question is practical as well as a bit academic.

Comment: you want a wrapper

Comment: I don't think so. I explained why I'd like to avoid the adapter/wrapper pattern and I also do not see how the Python wrapper technique with @ could help here. Maybe 2 minutes were not enought to completely understand my post? ;-)

Comment: those things with `@` are called decorators, not wrappers. If you don't go with a wrapper, then the answer is: no, Python does not provide any builtin/standard function/syntax to do what you want

Comment: How about adding the alias as an attribute? Eg, `f.connectsNodes=f.areFriends`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a alias like `Friendship.connectsNodes = Friendship.areFriends` to the class but it will only work locally. It's not going to affect the class if its imported from another file.

For your example code:

```
class Edge:
    def connectsNodes(self, n1, n2):
        return n1+n2

def my_graph_algo(edge):
    n1, n2 = 2, 5
    x = edge.connectsNodes(n1, n2)
    return x

e = Edge()
print(my_graph_algo(e))

class Friendship:
    def areFriends(self, f1, f2):
        return f1-f2

class Road:
    def connectsTowns(self, t1, t2):
        return t1*t2


Friendship.connectsNodes = Friendship.areFriends
f = Friendship()
print(my_graph_algo(f))

Road.connectsNodes = Road.connectsTowns
r = Road()
print(my_graph_algo(r))
```